# Parameters in TableAdapter /dataset/ C#

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, tableadapter

```
SELECT        iddocs, iddep, year
FROM            docs
WHERE        (@p1 = @p2)

this.docsTableAdapter.FillYear(this.test1DataSet2.docs,string1,string2);
```

or

```
 this.docsTableAdapter.FillBy(this.test1DataSet2.docs,string1,string2);
```

is not working. why?

Comment: What is _not working_ exactly? It is not clear what you asking.

Comment: result is empty. but it isn't in real